# CloudFormation with an ELB and its public dns

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudformation

I'm using Cloudformation to build a load balanced stack.

My concern is that each time the stack is recreated, the ELB public url will change, which will require a change in the website's route 53 domain alias, to point to the new ELB URL.

I can add Cloudformation configuration to automate this, but I'm wary that the site will go down for a few minutes each time the stack is recreated due to DNS propagation issues.

As I understand it, R53 will update the alias in about 60 seconds, but caching DNS servers may not obey the TTL and could take in the order of minutes to update.

An option is to run the old and new stack's together, but then the RDS instances in each VPC will need to be sync'd somehow.

Also it appears there isn't an option in Cloudformation to associate an existing ELB with a stack, so keeping an ELB separate to the stack seems to not be an option.

So what is the correct solution?  How can I avoid any noticeable downtime when replacing a production stack with a newly built CF stack.

Comment: But how often do you recreate your whole stack? And more specifically; where the new stack is in another VPC? It sounds like something that you shouldn't need to do except in more severe cases when you really need to redo a major part of the architecture. If you need to change the actual DNS record, I guess it's hard to avoid some glitches where users hit the new and old platform at the same time for a few seconds/minutes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a Stack Policy to prevent stack updates from updating the ELB resource.

documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/protect-stack-resources.html

example:

```
{
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Effect" : "Deny",
      "Action" : "Update:*",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource" : "*",
      "Condition" : {
        "StringEquals" : {
          "ResourceType" : ["AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Action" : "Update:*",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource" : "*"
    }
  ]
}
```